How to make a custom @Published propertyWrapper?
I have this property wrapper that forces a variable to be between 1 and 4.
    @propertyWrapper
struct Between1and4 {
  internal static let lowest = CGFloat(1.0)
  internal static let highest = CGFloat(4.0)
  private var value: CGFloat
  var wrappedValue: CGFloat {
    get { return value }
    set { value = CGFloat(min(max(Between1and4.lowest, newValue), Between1and4.highest))
    }
  }
  
  init(wrappedValue: CGFloat) {
    self.value = wrappedValue
  }
}

Now I want to create a property on an Observable class to be @Published.
Something like
final class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @published var scale:CGFloat
}

But I need this scale to be of type Between1and4, meaning this struct has to work like a @Published
How do I do that?

In theory, @Published @Between1and4 var scale: CGFloat should do the trick, but it doesn't. I see this error message:
Arguments to generic parameter 'Value' ('CGFloat' and 'Between1and4') are expected to be equal.

Cannot convert value of type 'ReferenceWritableKeyPath<ContentViewModel, CGFloat>' to expected argument type 'ReferenceWritableKeyPath<ContentViewModel, Between1and4>'


Do you mean you want to write something like @Published @Between1and4 var scale: CGFloat?

In theory, this should work, but it doesn't. I see this error message: Arguments to generic parameter 'Value' ('CGFloat' and 'Between1and4') are expected to be equal

Yes I’m aware, because @Published is kind of a special property wrapper. It uses a _enclosingInstance subscript, instead of wrappedValue like every other property wrapper does. This makes it very hard to compose other property wrappers with it unfortunately.

@Published is different from the usual property wrappers, in the sense that it doesn't de-sugar into the usual wrappedValue stuff.
@Published var foo = 0

// the above DOES NOT lower to this:
private var _foo: Published<Int> = .init(wrappedValue: 0)
var foo: Int {
    get { _foo.wrappedValue }
    set { _foo.wrappedValue = newValue }
}

// instead it lowers to:
private var _foo: Published<Int> = .init(wrappedValue: 0)
var foo: Int {
    get { _foo[_enclosingInstance: self, wrapped: \.foo, storage: \._foo] }
    set { _foo[_enclosingInstance: self, wrapped: \.foo, storage: \._foo] = newValue }
}

This _enclosingInstance subscript is a hidden feature that allows the property wrapper to have access to an instance of the enclosing class (in this case, ContentViewModel). Presumably, it needs to access the objectWillChange publisher. It's unlikely that this will be made an official feature.
The subscript is declared like this:
public static subscript<Root>(
    _enclosingInstance instance: Root,
    wrapped wrappedKeyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<Root, Value>,
    storage storageKeyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<Root, Self>
) -> Value

(Value here is the type parameter Value in Published<Value>)
If we apply the the above transformation to @Published @Between1and4 var scale, you will see that the wrapped parameter doesn't match. wrapped expects key path from ContentViewModel to Between1and4, but we are passing in a key path to CGFloat.
I assume you don't want the simple solution of just declaring an extra property and not using Between1and4 as a property wrapper:
@Published private var _scale: Between1and4 = .init(wrappedValue: 3)

var scale: CGFloat {
    get { _scale.wrappedValue }
    set { _scale.wrappedValue = newValue }
}


One approach to your problem is to add such an _enclosingInstance subscript to Between1and4, too, and have that subscript call objectWillChange, if and only if the enclosing instance is ObservableObject that uses the default implementation of objectWillChange.
static subscript<EnclosingSelf>(
    _enclosingInstance object: EnclosingSelf,
    wrapped wrappedKeyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<EnclosingSelf, CGFloat>,
    storage storageKeyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<EnclosingSelf, Between1and4>
) -> CGFloat {
    get { object[keyPath: storageKeyPath].wrappedValue }
    set {
        if let observableObject = object as? (any ObservableObject),
           let objectWillChange = (observableObject.objectWillChange as any Publisher) as? ObservableObjectPublisher {
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
        object[keyPath: storageKeyPath].wrappedValue = newValue
    }
}

Effectively, you create a @Published-like property wrapper, the also has the functionality of Between1and4.
In ContentViewModel, you don't need @Published anymore. Just write @Between1and4 and it will be automatically "published". Here is full example:
import SwiftUI
import Combine

final class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Between1and4 var scale: CGFloat = 1
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var model = ContentViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(model.scale, format: .number)
        // I deliberately set the range to 0...5 to show the effect of Between1and4
        Slider(value: $model.scale, in: 0...5)
    }
}

@propertyWrapper
struct Between1and4 {
    internal static let lowest = CGFloat(1.0)
    internal static let highest = CGFloat(4.0)
    private var value: CGFloat
    var wrappedValue: CGFloat {
        get { return value }
        set { value = CGFloat(min(max(Between1and4.lowest, newValue), Between1and4.highest))
        }
    }
    
    init(wrappedValue: CGFloat) {
        self.value = wrappedValue
    }
    
    static subscript<EnclosingSelf>(
        _enclosingInstance object: EnclosingSelf,
        wrapped wrappedKeyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<EnclosingSelf, CGFloat>,
        storage storageKeyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<EnclosingSelf, Between1and4>
    ) -> CGFloat {
        get { object[keyPath: storageKeyPath].wrappedValue }
        set {
            if let observableObject = object as? (any ObservableObject),
               let objectWillChange = (observableObject.objectWillChange as any Publisher) as? ObservableObjectPublisher {
                objectWillChange.send()
            }
            object[keyPath: storageKeyPath].wrappedValue = newValue
        }
    }
}

One advantage of this approach is that @Between1and4 will still work in general, outside of ObservableObjects. The subscript won't work when the enclosing type is a value type, but the compiler is apparently smart enough to fall back to using wrappedValue in that case. You can even surround the subscript with #if canImport(...) so that it still works without linking Combine/SwiftUI. The subscript can probably also be generated by a member macro.
One issue is that you can't get a Publisher using the $ prefix. You can technically put a CurrentValueSubject inside Between1and4 and use that as the publisher, but I think that's a bit overkill.

Thanks for the fantastic explanation, but please excuse my ignorance, but you lost me. What would be the final code for @Between1and4?

@Duck just add the subscript (the final code snippet) to @Between1and4.

@Duck I edited the answer with a full example, in case you are still confused.

fantastic. THANKS!!!!

To achieve similar behavior with your custom @Between1and4 property wrapper, you need to manually create a publisher inside your property wrapper and provide it as the projectedValue.
@propertyWrapper
struct Between1and4 {
    internal static let lowest = CGFloat(1.0)
    internal static let highest = CGFloat(4.0)
    
    private var value: CGFloat
    private let subject: CurrentValueSubject<CGFloat, Never>
    
    var projectedValue: AnyPublisher<CGFloat, Never> {
        subject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    var wrappedValue: CGFloat {
        get { value }
        set {
            let clampedValue = CGFloat(min(max(Between1and4.lowest, newValue), Between1and4.highest))
            value = clampedValue
            subject.send(value)
        }
    }
    
    init(wrappedValue: CGFloat) {
        let clampedValue = CGFloat(min(max(Between1and4.lowest, wrappedValue), Between1and4.highest))
        self.value = clampedValue
        self.subject = CurrentValueSubject(clampedValue)
    }
}

How to Use:
final class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Between1and4 var scale: CGFloat = 1.0
    
    var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    
    init() {
        cancellable = $scale.sink { newValue in
            print("Scale changed to: \(newValue)")
        }
    }
}


For some reason, this does not work for me. scale is being listed by two elements. One of them does not change as scale changes... don't ask me why. If I change scale to @Published, it works.

ObservableObject is just for your model data, for your view data it's @State. You can create your own property wrapper @Between1and4 that wraps @State and does the limiting like this:
@propertyWrapper
struct Between1and4: DynamicProperty { // DynamicProperty is needed to use property wrappers

    internal static let lowest = CGFloat(1.0)
    internal static let highest = CGFloat(4.0)

    static func limit(x: CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
        return CGFloat(min(max(Between1and4.lowest, x), Between1and4.highest))
    }

    @State var value: CGFloat

    init(wrappedValue: CGFloat) {
        self.value = Self.limit(x: wrappedValue)
    }

    var wrappedValue: CGFloat {
        get { return value }
        nonmutating set {
            value = Self.limit(x: newValue)
        }
    }
}

    struct ContentView: View {
        @Between1and4 var number = 0

        var body: some View {
            Button("\(number)") { // it will not go higher than 4
                number += 1
            }

